# How does my computer know the maximum resolution & refresh rate of the display?

Tags: windows, display, resolution, edid

So I have a laptop with display of 2560x1440 resolution and 240Hz refresh rate. From my understanding, OS detects supported & preferred resolutions from EDID information.

I've used `dumpEDID` tool to dump my EDID information and here are the results:

```
PS> .\DumpEDID.exe -a
DumpEDID v1.07
Copyright (c) 2006 - 2018 Nir Sofer
Web site: http://www.nirsoft.net

*****************************************************************
Active                   : Yes
Registry Key             : DISPLAY\SHP153C\4&8e4a58&0&UID8388688
Monitor Name             : LQ156T1JW04
Manufacture Week         : 45 / 2020
ManufacturerID           : 4173 (0x104D)
ProductID                : 5436 (0x153C)
Serial Number (Numeric)  : 0 (0x00000000)
EDID Version             : 1.4
Display Gamma            : 2.20
Image Size               : 34.4 X 19.4 cm (15.5 Inch)
Maximum Image Size       : 34 X 19 cm (15.3 Inch)
Maximum Resolution       : 2560 X 1440
Support Standby Mode     : No
Support Suspend Mode     : No
Support Low-Power Mode   : No
Support Default GTF      : Yes
Digital                  : Yes

Supported Display Modes  :
    2560 X 1440  60 Hz

*****************************************************************
```

It says only supported mode is `2560 X 1440  60 Hz`, but I have no issues using `2560 X 1440  240 Hz` so how does my computer know that my display can be used at `2560 X 1440  240 Hz` settings?

Comment: The driver has information as well and (if it's a generic one) it won't really know. But you can always try to just output and see if it works. This was something that happened more often with CRTs. Especially with notebooks (this seems to be one) things might be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

DumpEDID on my computer only shows a few resolutions and modes.
I can see many more in *Settings > System > Display*.

I can also list more combinations using the
[Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU).

My conclusion is that DumpEDID does a poor job of dumping the EDID,
and your display driver does a much better job of it.